# JSHint "X is not defined" is wrong

Tags: ember.js, jshint

I have an ember.js project (ember_cli) with the following:

Sessions.hbs:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-1 col-xl-1">Username:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xl-4">
          {{view Ember.TextField classBinding=":sessions-query" valueBinding="FilterUserName"}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xl-1">
            <button id="query-sessions" {{action "querySessions"}}>Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

sessions.js (controller):

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    querySessions: function () {
      var arr_simple_params = {};
      if ((typeof FilterUserName !== "undefined") && (FilterUserName !== "")) {
        arr_simple_params["user_name"] = FilterUserName;
      }
      ....
    }
  }
});
```

JSHint gives me:
`controllers/sessions.js: line 25, col 55, 'FilterUserName' is not defined.`

But when I actually use the variable (the rest of the method is using it to build a query string) everything works

So I was wondering why it happens (and not just suppress the warning...)

Comment: Are you importing FilterUserName above using `import`?

Comment: I beleive not. can you please elaborate/provide a reference to the import you are referring to?

Answer (score 3):

JSHint is upset because you’re referencing a global variable. You should either import `FilterUserName` like this, at the beginning of the controller:

```
import FilterUserName from 'path-to-filter'
```

or warn JSHint that you’re using a global:

```
/* global FilterUserName */
```

You can also add `FilterUserName` to `.jshintrc` if you’re using it elsewhere.

Comment: so Im guessing I'm doing something wrong. It is a simple valueBinding. Ember doesn't have a solution for that?

Comment: Oh, I didn’t see that you were using that name as a binding. To access bound variables, you need to use `get`: `this.get('FilterUserName')`

Comment: well I tried it before (and rechecked it now) - when I do `console.log(this.get('FilterUserName'));` I get `undefined`

Comment: Did you enter anything into the field before checking the value of `FilterUserName`? I’m confused about what you’re trying to do. Your use of `valueBinding` means that the `FilterUserName` property on your controller will be set to whatever you enter into the field.

Comment: of course I entered something in the textField. That's the weird thing this question is about - when I tried the "right thing" `this.get('FilterUserName')` - I get undefined, when I use `FilterUserName` "directly" in the controller - I get a JSHint warning but it works...